# D3.js not showing labels on first SVG after second SVG created

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YedQog

If I comment out the line `donut2.create(petData());` to only create one chart, it works fine. However, when that line is left in and I use the logic to create two distinct pie charts, the labels disappear for the first chart. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why.

Any help appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  var donut1 = new DonutCharts('#money');
  donut1.create(moneyData());

  var donut2 = new DonutCharts('#pets');
  // donut2.create(petData());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`var donuts = d3.selectAll('.donut');`

do

`var donuts = charts.selectAll('.donut');`

**Reason:**

`d3.selectAll('.donut');`
will select the previous created chart and so the problem, that is the reason why the last graph text comes.

working code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQXJxa?editors=0010)

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver. I would kiss you if I could! I was pulling my hair out trying to find where I'd gone wrong. Thank you so, so much.